# Attribute error when calling function

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am coding a date program using classes and inheritance. I am trying to define the function advance, which makes the seconds, minute, and hour advance according to some rules. I defined second, minute, and hour as another class called "Counter". The problem is, when calling the functions defined in counter, I get an error saying :

```
while self._hora!=self._hora.getMax():
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getMax'
```

This is the code of the class Reloj. I will also post the code to a git with the whole code so you can check it out.

```
class Reloj(object):

    _segundo = Contador(0, 59)
    _minuto = Contador(0, 59)
    _hora = Contador(0, 24)

    def __init__(self, s, minu, h):

        self._segundo = Contador(0, 59)
        self._minuto = Contador(0, 59)
        self._hora = Contador(0, 24)
        self.set(s,minu,h)


    def set(self, s, minu, h):

        self._segundo.setCuenta(s)
        self._minuto.setCuenta(minu)
        self._hora.setCuenta(h)

    def tic(self):

         while self._segundo != self._segundo.getMax():

             self._segundo=self._segundo.getCuenta
             while self._minuto!=self._minuto.getMax():

                 self._minuto=self._minuto.getCuenta
                 while self._hora!=self._hora.getMax():
                     self._hora=self._hora.getCuenta

                 else:
                     self._hora.contar()
             else:
                 self._minuto.contar()
         else:
             self._segundo.contar()

    def display(self):

        return print (str(self._segundo.getCuenta())+":"+str(self._minuto.getCuenta())+":"+str(self._hora.getCuenta()))
```

CODE:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ce55e50f3c3f53e937279475c0336bc

Comment: Probably not related, but don't create a bunch of class-variables only to shadow them immediately in the initializer.

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: But **very likely** you are forgetting to actually *call* a method. You are doing that several times in your code, e.g. `self._segundo=self._segundo.getCuenta` should be `self._segundo = self._segundo.getCuenta()`

Comment: As an aside, that seems like an approach prone to errors. You overwriting the value `self.segundo = self._segundo.getCuenta()`, but `self._segundo` was a `Contador` object, now it is an `int`. Smells bad to me.

Comment: So yeah, the *proximal* cause is `self._hora=self._hora.getCuenta`, but you will run in to very similar errors because you've made the same mistake repeatedly in that method. As an aside, unless your pofessor or something is forcing you to write a bunch of getters, please don't. This is Python, not Java. We don't use getters and setters for encapsulation, we use properties, and they are only necessary when you actually need to modify the behavior. So Most of your `Contador` class can be eliminated, and overall, your code will look much cleaner

Comment: I am using a set of functions and classes defined by my teacher. I dont find much sense in the set functions.

Comment: There is sense to that approach in languages like Java, because it provides what is called "encapsulation". However, in Python, there are better approaches. Indeed, your entire code looks like someone used to writing Java is trying to write a Python class definition. Quite common. But just do what your professor requires. Unfortunately, a lot of programs have switched from Java to Python, and they insist on teaching Python in Java... My biggest pet peeve is the use of double-underscores to try ot mimic Java/C++ private access modifiers. That isn't what name-mangling is for!

Comment: Still it didnt solve the problem. For some reason I can call the function getMax for second and minute but not for hour.

Comment: Dude, I already explained to you, your code is *replete with this very same error*, and that's just what I got from glancing at it. You will likely have a lot of debugging to do. You probably shouldn't write more code than you can get to work, because now you've built a house of cards. Have fun.

Comment: As I pointed out, your entire approach is flawed. Even if you correctly do something like `self._segundo = self._segundo.getCuenta()` now `self._segundo` is no longer a `Contador` object, it is an `int`, and when your while-loop checks `while self._hora!=self._hora.getMax():` it will fail after the first iteration, because `int` objects don't have `getMax`. The reason it is failing for `self._hora` first is because it is the most nested loop, so it reaches it's second iteration first. You probably need to keep local variable references to the result something like `h = self._hora.get_cuenta()`